# What can I do to automatic run a bat file when a new item on a folder is added?

Tags: powershell

I have a ps1 file which contains the code and a bat file which when i double click runs the code.
The ps1 file renames all files in that folder.
Here is the code:

```
get-childitem -path C:\Users\ASUS\Videos\Downloads\*.mp4 | foreach {rename-item $_ $_.name.replace("_"," ")}
```

How can I run the bat file to automatically rename all files that are added to that folder?

Comment: You can use the `FileSystemWatcher`. Here you can read more about it: [Monitoring Folders for File Changes](https://powershell.one/tricks/filesystem/filesystemwatcher)

Comment: What code should I use exactly? I'm not very good at coding so I don't understand some of it.

Answer (score 0):

I saw @olaf mentioned FileSystemWatcher and, honestly, it one of the better options for what you're trying to do.

Alternatively, you can use [Task Scheduler](https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-properly-schedule-a-task-to-run-powershell-script) to run at specific times, dates, actions, etc. There's also no need to point to the bat file, it can run ps1 files just as easy without having to have .bat execute the .ps1.

Change your ps1 to the following. It's passing only the items that were created less than 30 minutes ago; can be changed to days, minutes, etc. Then, it's just renaming them(:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\ASUS\Videos\Downloads\*.mp4 | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30)}| foreach {rename-item $_.FullName $_.name.replace("_"," ")}
```

Comment: What trigger should I use for detecting new files?

Comment: also can i use filesystemwatcher without opening the ps1 file. I want it to be fully automated.

Comment: you can just add it to the script to check for time, days, months, etc. Will edit my post now

Comment: Just modified your code to fit your needs